# How to do integration testing on an app depending on injected service with a Mock for the service?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side

I don't think it matters what the application is - Asp.NET, Blazor, WPF ... whatever -- if dependency injection is implemented, say:

```
class Foo {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddSingleton<IDispatcher, DispatchProvider>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticator, AuthenticationProvider>();
    }
}
```

... then:

```
class Bar {
    public Bar (IDispatcher dispatcher) {
        // do something with dispatcher...
    }
}
```

... the dependency creates a *not-so-straight-forward-approach* to unit testing.

Obviously, if I'm going to perform integration testing on `Bar` (with a dependency on `IDispatcher`), I don't necessarily want to fire up the relevant resources.

If `Bar` is a standalone object, I can create a `Mock<IDispatcher>` and manually inject into `Bar`; however, in my case, I am developing a Blazor component. The component has a dependency on `IDispatch` and another component on `IAuthenticator`.

The only thing I can come up with to alternatively inject a *mock* is to do the following:

```
if (!isTest)) {
    services.AddSingleton<IDispatcher, DispatchProvider>();
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticator, AuthenticationProvider>();
} else {
    services.AddSingleton<IDispatcher, MockDispatchProvider>();
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticator, MockAuthenticationProvider>();
}
```

Here, I have a separate class library with just the *mocks* in it. My web app has to reference that .DLL which really stinks.

Is there a more practical solution? I really don't like having to do this.

Comment: is your `ConfigureServices` really outside of `Startup` class?

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: @Andy: no, in my case, `Startup` is the bootstrap; however, it does not have to be so I did not use it. `Foo` is *any bootstrap equivalent that configures the `HostBuilder`*. I"m using MS test.

Comment: OK -- So you said `HostBuilder`, so you are most likely doing "integration" tests where you start a `TestServer` that would instantiate your API endpoints, correct? Then you'd make `[Fact]` that would use an `HttpClient` created by `TestServer.CreateClient`. Sorry for all the questions, I'm just trying to figure out what you are trying to do to give a good answer.

Comment: It is probably a more accurate account of what I am actually doing; ***integration testing*** rather than *unit test*.

Comment: OK -- So, you shouldn't have to do mock services then. You would start your webapplication/API up normally where it would inject normally using your normal `startup.cs`. If you'd like to see how that's typically done, I would be more than happy to show you.

Comment: I don't have all the services even built behind the web app. So, I have to *mock* something. I'm designing the service's API based on what I do with the app itself.